# Error str object not callable in vowel counting program

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.5

Hi I am trying to write a program that counts the vowels in a sentence and then prints out the count of each vowel individually.

```
Sentence = input("Please enter sentence: ")
a = 0
e = 0
i = 0
o = 0
u = 0
for index in range(0, len(Sentence) - 1):
    if Sentence(index) == "a":
        a = a + 1
    elif Sentence(index) == "e":
        e = e + 1
    elif Sentence(index) == "i":
        i = i + 1
    elif Sentence(index) == "o":
        o = o + 1
    elif Sentence(index) == "u":
        u = u + 1
print(a, e, i, o, u)
```

Getting the following error :

> Please enter sentence:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "script.py", line 8, in 
>       if Sentence(index) == "a": TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Command exited with non-zero status 1

Any help would be be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: which language is this in? please tag the used language. Some languages use `" "` for strings and `' '` for characters and strings might not be comparable with `==`

Comment: I'm using Python

Comment: Please tag python in the question then

Comment: You must use brackets `[]` instead of parens `()` to get arrays (or mappings) elements : `Sentence[index]`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like python to me.

```
for index in range(0, len(Sentence) - 1):
    if Sentence[index] == "a": #You have Sentence(index)
        a = a + 1
    elif Sentence[index] == "e":
        e = e + 1
    elif Sentence[index] == "i":
        i = i + 1
    elif Sentence[index] == "o":
        o = o + 1
    elif Sentence[index] == "u":
        u = u + 1
print(a, e, i, o, u)
```